# Trying to call the Exit Shellcode in a c program

Tags: assembly, c, buffer-overflow, shellcode, x86-64

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>

char shellcode[] = "\xb8\x3c\x00\x00\x00"
                   "\xbf\x14\x00\x00\x00"
                   "\x0f\x05";

int main()
{
    uint64_t *ret;
    ret = (uint64_t *)&ret + 2;
    (*ret) = (uint64_t)shellcode;
}
```

so here what i am trying to do is run the exit shellcode by modifying the rets address to the shellcodes address and exiting the c program with status 20.

```
Reading symbols from ./Shellcode...
(gdb) l
1       #include<stdio.h>
2       #include<stdint.h>
3
4       char shellcode[] = "\xb8\x3c\x00\x00\x00"
5                          "\xbf\x14\x00\x00\x00"
6                          "\x0f\x05";
7
8       int main()
9       {
10
(gdb) 
11          uint64_t *ret;
12          ret = (uint64_t *)&ret + 2;
13          (*ret) = (uint64_t)shellcode;
14      }
(gdb) 
Line number 15 out of range; Shellcode.c has 14 lines.
(gdb) break 12
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1129: file Shellcode.c, line 12.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/kali/oscp/asm/32/Shellcode 

Breakpoint 1, main () at Shellcode.c:12
12          ret = (uint64_t *)&ret + 2;
(gdb) print /x &shellcode
$1 = 0x555555558028
(gdb) x/8xg $rsp
0x7fffffffdf70: 0x0000555555555150      0x00007ffff7e12d0a
0x7fffffffdf80: 0x00007fffffffe068      0x0000000100000000
0x7fffffffdf90: 0x0000555555555125      0x00007ffff7e127cf
0x7fffffffdfa0: 0x0000000000000000      0xd60b04d41db666f5
(gdb) s
13          (*ret) = (uint64_t)shellcode;
(gdb) x/8xg $rsp
0x7fffffffdf70: 0x0000555555555150      0x00007ffff7e12d0a
0x7fffffffdf80: 0x00007fffffffe068      0x0000000100000000
0x7fffffffdf90: 0x0000555555555125      0x00007ffff7e127cf
0x7fffffffdfa0: 0x0000000000000000      0xd60b04d41db666f5
(gdb) print /x $rip
$2 = 0x555555555135
(gdb) s
14      }
(gdb) x/8xg $rsp
0x7fffffffdf70: 0x0000555555555150      0x0000555555558028
0x7fffffffdf80: 0x00007fffffffe068      0x0000000100000000
0x7fffffffdf90: 0x0000555555555125      0x00007ffff7e127cf
0x7fffffffdfa0: 0x0000000000000000      0xd60b04d41db666f5
(gdb) print /x $rip
$3 = 0x555555555148
(gdb) s
0x0000555555558028 in shellcode ()
(gdb) print /x $rip
$4 = 0x555555558028
(gdb) x/8xg $rsp
0x7fffffffdf80: 0x00007fffffffe068      0x0000000100000000
0x7fffffffdf90: 0x0000555555555125      0x00007ffff7e127cf
0x7fffffffdfa0: 0x0000000000000000      0xd60b04d41db666f5
0x7fffffffdfb0: 0x0000555555555040      0x0000000000000000
(gdb) s
Single stepping until exit from function shellcode,
which has no line number information.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555558028 in shellcode ()
```

The shellcode address does fall into `rip` but the shellcode does not execute or something that i am unable to understand.
so like what should I do to make my shellcode run and have an exit status of 20.

Comment: how do you compile this? I have no problem successfully running this in a quick test. Though you never set status code to 20 (only copy from `eax`)

Comment: This code "\xbf\x14\x00\x00\x00" sets the exit status code, im just wondering to remove the 0x00 from the shellcode to prevent string termination.

Comment: No, in this case `\x00` do not matter. Make sure that you disable NX (`-zstackexec`) so that the stack can be executable so again how do you compile this?.

Comment: i did use -z execstack, but still no luck, it works in the ubuntu bionic versions but not on the fossa one